# Regex exec in while loop returning null even when there are matches

Tags: javascript, regex, while-loop, do-while

From my research, regex `replace` is not async. So I am a little confused as to why matching and replacing in a `do-while` loop fails to match sometimes.

I have created a snippet below that optionally "double checks" if the value has any matches in it, but i have no idea why double checking actually prevents it from ignoring matches.

You will see in the console, that when `injectableRegex.exec()` is run twice in the `do-while` loop, that it correctly replaces all matches.

**Update**: Even this method is not consistent, as I find sometimes the doubleCheck section correctly matches, and then the subsequent `exec` call fails

```js
const getInjectedPhrase = (phrase, injections, doubleCheck) => {
  let value = phrase;
  // only need to attempt to replace the injectables in the phrase is we've been passed injections
  if (injections && phrase.length > 1) {
    const injectableRegex = /{{\s?([\w-]+)\s?}}/g; // find any matching injectable, and extract its key
    let match;
    window.console.log('initial phrase:', phrase);
    // check if dictionary value contains injectable sections ie. sections surrounded by {{ }}
    do {
      // WHY IS THIS A THING!?
      if (doubleCheck) {
        injectableRegex.exec(value)
      }
      match = injectableRegex.exec(value);
      if (match) {
        /*
        match[0] -> {{ x }}
        match[1] -> x
        */
        const injectionValue = injections[match[1]];

        const injectionValueType = typeof injectionValue;
        if (
          injectionValueType === "string" ||
          injectionValueType === "number"
        ) {
          // globally replace the value with the injection's value
          value = value.replace(new RegExp(match[0], "g"), `${injectionValue}`);
          window.console.log('partial replace phrase:', value);
        }
      }
    } while (match !== null);
  }
  window.console.log('returned phrase:', value);
  return value;
};

window.console.log('WITHOUT DOUBLE CHECKING');
getInjectedPhrase(
  "foo {{partialCount}} of {{count}} bars", {
    partialCount: 3,
    count: 4
  },
  false
);
window.console.log('USING DOUBLE CHECKING');
getInjectedPhrase(
  "foo {{partialCount}} of {{count}} bars", {
    partialCount: 3,
    count: 4
  },
  true
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the regular expression keeps a `lastIndex` property, which keeps track of the end index of the last match. In

```
foo {{partialCount}} of {{count}} bars
```

matching

```
{{partialCount}}
```

results in the `lastIndex` property being set to `20` afterwards - the location past the second `}`.

Then, when you *reassign* the string to

```
foo 3 of {{count}} bars
```

using the same regex to try to match will start *at index 20* of that string, which is *past* the `{{count}}` part, so the match fails.

One option is to manually reset the `lastIndex` to 0 each time:

```js
const getInjectedPhrase = (phrase, injections, doubleCheck) => {
  let value = phrase;
  // only need to attempt to replace the injectables in the phrase is we've been passed injections
  if (injections && phrase.length > 1) {
    const injectableRegex = /{{\s?([\w-]+)\s?}}/g; // find any matching injectable, and extract its key
    let match;
    window.console.log('initial phrase:', phrase);
    // check if dictionary value contains injectable sections ie. sections surrounded by {{ }}
    do {
      injectableRegex.lastIndex = 0;
      match = injectableRegex.exec(value);
      if (match) {
        /*
        match[0] -> {{ x }}
        match[1] -> x
        */
        const injectionValue = injections[match[1]];

        const injectionValueType = typeof injectionValue;
        if (
          injectionValueType === "string" ||
          injectionValueType === "number"
        ) {
          // globally replace the value with the injection's value
          value = value.replace(new RegExp(match[0], "g"), `${injectionValue}`);
          window.console.log('partial replace phrase:', value);
        }
      }
    } while (match !== null);
  }
  window.console.log('returned phrase:', value);
  return value;
};

window.console.log('WITHOUT DOUBLE CHECKING');
getInjectedPhrase(
  "foo {{partialCount}} of {{count}} bars", {
    partialCount: 3,
    count: 4
  },
  false
);
```

A better option would be to `replace` *all at once*, with a callback function, no need to manually iterate, replace, and reset the regex object:

```js
const getInjectedPhrase = (str, obj) => str.replace(
  /{{\s?([\w-]+)\s?}}/g,
  (_, key) => obj[key]
);

console.log(
  getInjectedPhrase(
    "foo {{partialCount}} of {{count}} bars", {
      partialCount: 3,
      count: 4
    },
  )
);
```

Comment: I knew i must be missing something super obvious! Thats an interesting gotcha around lastIndex. Thanks so much, will mark as answer when it lets me in 3 minutes

Comment: Also, thanks so much for the MUCH simpler replace function!